# How to desaturate markers for Google Maps API in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am looking at the following [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/FFm9NmSfjw0?t=75). it shows a short sample codes to desaturate a marker, but there is no mention of how to combine it with the Marker.

```
ColorMatrix desatMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
desatMatrix.setSaturation (restaurantRating);
ColorFilter paintColorFilter = new ColorMatrixcolorFilter(desatMatrix);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColorFilter(paintColorFilter);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas (newImage);
canvas.drawBitmap(oldImage, 0,0, paint);
```

the question is how to I now add the codes above into my marker creation method?

the video says to "apply the filter to the marker image", but i got no idea what that means.

```
private MarkeOptions ceateStartMarkerOptions (Location location, String title, String snippet){

    return new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactor.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_my_marker_icon)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippet);
}
```

I add the marker directly into the GoogleMap mMap using

```
currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(createStartMarkerOptions (location, "",""));
```

Comment: read `BitmapDescriptorFactory` documentation

Comment: @pskink, is there a particular section that i should zoom into ? there's no mention of applying the ColorFilter to the Marker. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory

Comment: what is `newImage` ? then find how to create `BitmapDescriptor` based on `newImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `newImage` is a Bitmap where you want all your drawings.
You can pass it to your MarkerOptions like this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(newImage)));
```